# Mac OSX Ctrl+Shift+Tab not working on USB full-size Apple Keyboard

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, key-binding

I noticed today that while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> behaves as expected on my MacBook Air, it does nothing across apps (I tried *Google Chrome* and *iTerm*) when I'm using my USB-connected full-size Apple keyboard. I've recently remapped <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> through the OSX Keyboard System Preferences. I've confirmed that the modifier key mappings are identical for both keyboards.

What should I try to diagnose/solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Does a known good keyboard work? I had a similar issue and something weird was up with the keyboard I normally used.

Have you attempted to reset NVRAM? ( CMD +OPT +P+R on startup. Let the Mac chime twice)